# Scala: filter Seq[] (make a diff)

Tags: scala, playframework

I have two `Seq[_]`es in my Play application.

Now I want to make a diff of those and get as a result an Seq with all items which are not in the other one.

I tried to use `.filter()` but I don't know if thats a good way

How can I achieve this?

thanks in advance

**Update** ... PseudoCode Example

I have two `Seq[]`

1.) Seq[CarsInStock]
Attributes[ID, Brand, Color]
`[{1,Porsche,Red},{3,Mercedes,Blue}]`

2.) Seq[CarsAfterSale]
Attributes[ID, Brand, Color,Doors,Windows]
`[{1,Porsche,Red,4,10}]`

Now I wan't to make a diff between the two `seq[]`. As result I want to get the Object `{3,Mercedes,Blue}]` because it is in stock, but after sales I have to know which ones I have to remove from stock.
I want to recognize the difference by the `ID` of the elements

Comment: Please provide your code snippet.

Comment: I don't have it anymore. Removed it because it was totally wrong

Comment: if you would share idea what you tried so far and what is expected from your point of view, this would definitely help

Comment: @Pavel I've added an example above, does that help?

Comment: you will need to convert Seq.2 to the same Seq type as Seq.1 and diff will work correctly, yes, that helps

Comment: Why aren't you using a `Set` and overridding `equals`?

Comment: See from docs -> A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements. if this is satisfy your requirement, you can use Set

Comment: Is there no way to do this without transforming Seq2 to same type as Seq2?

Comment: Off course there is way to do this different way -> implement your custom diff, the question is why you need extra problems in your logic??

Comment: In my case those are `Seq[]` from two different Models. Can I do something with an iteration?

Comment: You can not do this without additional iteration because different objects are different. So you will need to convert one of the type to other in the explicit or implicit way (like compare by fields or so).  In your example Seq2 will be always different because it has "Doors,Windows" and first not.

Comment: In the case, you want to compare exactly structure you described, you need to convert all elements to some "object with free structure" type like JsonObject. 

And if you receive that Seq from different models then you need to change the point that generates that Seq, you must have a point that generates the same type of the different models if you wont to compare them later. 

You can think about some parent interface that is the same for both of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply filter out all cars whose `id` exist in the other `Seq`.

```
stock.filterNot(c => afterSale.exists(_.id == c.id))
```

Comment: I tried it this way: `val bla = prerequisitesInDatabase.filterNot(c => step.prerequisites.get.exists( x => x.id.get == c.id && x.processTemplate_id == c.processtemplate))`

Comment: But In the list are all the ones from first seq

Comment: Can't really tell you anything else without knowing more about the data structures you're actually working with.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you expect the second `Seq` to be short, you can probably optimize it by creating a `Set` of `id`s:

```
val afterSaleIds = afterSale.iterator.map(_.id).toSet    
stock.filterNot(c => afterSaleIds.contains(c.id))
```